# The importance of note taking in mathematics

Tags: undergraduate-education, lecture-notes

I'm asking this question right now due to the fact that a lower back problem has made it very difficult for me to do much but lie down for large sections of the day when it flares up, and the fact that it is quite difficult to take notes when lying on your back.

How important would one say taking notes is to the mathematical learning process? What other ways are there of learning?

I've always taken notes in the past, but the development of this back problem has made it very painful to stand or sit longer than necessary at times, and during those times much of my sitting time must go towards doing the problem sets.

Comment: @celeriko  Anecdotes are acceptable, but research is preferable.

Comment: Is this at home simply reading? Or doing exercises? Or in a classroom?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins  Undergraduate course

Comment: Okay, it's for an undergraduate course. But what component of the work -- At-home reading? Doing exercises? In a classroom lecture? All of the above?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Taking notes of the lecture material, from the lecture notes most often

Comment: How are you doing on the problem sets now that you are having back troubles?  Since people learn differently, your own experience may be the most important..

Comment: I don't understand -- you're taking notes from the notes?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Writing helps one remember things, in general

Comment: Gregory Chudnovsky has Myasthenia gravis, an autoimmune disease, because of which he has to lay himself down frequently. He scribbles in his bed. I, too, have an autoimmune disease -- Ankylosing Spondylitis. I cannot stay in any position for a longer period. Don't even ask how hard it is to press a pen against paper. I usually resort to typing on Scientific Workplace or using a mobile phone with a stylus to aid writing. I keep track of stuff by writing only what's necessary. This has the added advantage (a great one at that) to look for main arguments in order to scribble them down. (cont)

Comment: (cont from converted answer) I hardly took notes in my class because I simply couldn't anymore. I asked a friend for permission to photocopy his notes after each class. This freed my need of having to write in class and I could pay more attention to what was being taught. I could google stuff up later, if needed. I also sat at the back benches so if I needed to move, I could do so without being a distraction to the class. Kudos to all my professors for accommodating that.

Comment: (cont from converted answer) You'll have to learn which position best suits you. Remember, scribbling is frequently required but, for me, it worked to write only what was necessary. For instance, I only wrote only definitions and theorem/lemma statements and that, too, in very symbolic notation.

Hope this helps and hope you recover soon. Get yourself checked/treated properly.

Comment: @Coward I am getting treated, but there's not much that can be done when they can't really figure out what's going on

Comment: You might be interested in http://mathoverflow.net/q/12638/14319 and http://mathoverflow.net/q/12898/14319

Comment: @Nethesis Among _real_ mathematicians, your "Writing helps one remember things, in general" is known as "Reading pencil in hand" which, whether they recognize it or not and other than possibly a few geniuses, is the way they learn.

Comment: I never learned anything in math classes or seminars until I stopped taking notes. I listen better if I don't take notes. The key in a lecture is to get the ideas. Later one has to sit with pen and paper, but even then it is usually more productive to think before putting pen to paper. Now I only take notes in seminars that treat a topic I already know something about.

Comment: @schremmer I'm wondering if that phrase is parsed as "a reading pencil in hand" or "reading with a pencil in hand" or "... reading, pencil in hand,...".

Comment: @ryang Don't see what the differences are. In any case, what I meant is that reading is not passive but is a means towards "seeing" something. So, what the pencil is for is to record the stages of "seeing" as one gets along.

Comment: @schremmer Those are 3 distinct constructions/readings (each with different surrounding words/punctuation), but their general meaning is of course as you’ve just described. I found that phrase apt/useful, and immediately wondered how to (grammatically) parse it.

Comment: @yang Now I see the differences. (I understand fast but you have to explain at length.) So, I think that I would say "read-pencil-in-hand" in the case of mathematics because, as I said, here, the pencil is integral to the reading, somewhat like the baton of a Conductor, as opposed to, for instance in the case of reading Camilleri's Montalbano, "read, Italian-French-dictionary-in-hand" because my command of Italian is sufficient to do without it. What do you say?